# How to add custom message while accessing user location?

Tags: ios, core-location

How to add custom message: Allow Location Access to use your location? instead of Allow “Location Access” to access your location while you are using the app?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize the main part of the message. You only get to customize the reason. And your current reason is not helpful to the user. Replace your:

> This app needs access to your location!

with a short message that explains *why* your app needs access.

Comment: Thankyou. Can we change the "Don't Allow" to "Cancel" in the location dialog?

Comment: No. As I said, you can only provide the "reason". That's all you have control over.

Comment: How to add the reason? Can anyone please share the code in objective C